# Plus, Minus, Ground and the damn noise

Tags: amplifier, noise, hum

I am a relatively newbie here and I am trying to build this project... so do not kick me hard and forget any stupid errors you see on the project. I appreciate any suggestions, criticism, etc., preferably with instructions on what to do. Talk to me like I am 3 years old. Show pictures...

[image]

Open this image on another window, or you will not see it with enough zoom.

This is a 4 stereo input switch. You press the key and you select the input key you want to send to the output.

First look at my power supply. I am using LM7810 and I have a resistor divider. So, My power supply is delivering +5V, 0 and -5V.

By having "negative voltage", I can setup the audio on the middle of the range and supply the MAX359 with positive and negative voltages.

I turn the whole thing on and it works almost perfectly. Every press of the switch and the next input is selected.

Now look at pins 8 and 9 of MAX359E (the switch). These lines enter on the potentiometers. The midle of the potentiometers go to the amplifier (TEA2025) and the other side of the potentiometer goes to -5V.

I have two problems with this circuit:

1. Noise. It is humming like hell on the output.
2. Another thing is that I am not sure if some voltages are correct. Suppose I put the multimeter's positive probe after C16 and the negative probe at -5V. If input U4 is not the selected input, that voltage is 5V as expected. As soon as I select U4, the voltage drops to 2.42V. I was not expecting that to drop.

Any ideas? Please remember to talk to me like I am 3 years old. Thanks.

Comment: Your power supply ground will not work. You can not 'divide' a 10V supply into two 5V one with 100K resistors, even worse is omitting the capacitors there. And no, I can't explain in words for a 3 year old why that does not work. The average three your old does not understand 'impedance, resistance etc.

Comment: Use two 9 volt batteries, and get better performance.  Then sit back and think about why these 2 batteries do work.

Comment: Try looking at the answers to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366488/trying-to-build-a-symmetrical-power-supply-from-a-vdc-input-without-the-problems/366526#366526) to see what a proper power supply splitter looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now look at pins 8 and 9 of MAX359E (the switch). These lines enter on the potentiometers. The midle of the potentiometers go to the amplifier (TEA2025) and the other side of the potentiometer goes to -5V.

- Why? R7 should be a volume control, right? Then the lower end should go to **GND**, not V-. Because your signal has positive and negative voltages.
- U2 has the same problem, outer GND is tied to -5V instead of GND. This will give you serious clipping.

Please solve these two problems first. Then, you may need to have the GND tighter than 50µA, the maximum current your voltage divider R3/R4 allows. Think of an active voltage divider using e.g. an op-amp unity-gain follower behind this resistor network. Also, create the virtual GND directly from the input, then use one 7805 and one 7905 to regulate +5V and -5V separately.

Comment: thanks I will modify the circuit. BTW, can you point me to a kind of circuit that may be suitable for this power supply.

Comment: This is a simple virtual GND: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNmSy.jpg The purpose of the op-amp is providing more current into GND without having an excessive current from V+ to V-.

Comment: I have did everything you said: 1) connected the other side of the pots to GND. Connected all grounds of the input and output jacks to GND. Added an op amp to stabilize the virtual ground and now the op amp output is the new GND. Now, when I turn it on, I hear a sound like an helicopter on the output. I do not have an oscilloscope but I tried to measure +V and -V and they are oscillating like hell

Comment: If it's "helicopter sound", chances are you are still having the wrong reference potential somewhere so the 100/120Hz from the supply are added to your signal. Without having an oscilloscope, debugging this is complicated. You should cut down your device into several parts you could debug separately.

Comment: so, just to confirm: 1) I should connect this virtual GND to the ground of all audio jacks and to the other side of the potentiometers, so I have the audio in the middle of the DC rail. The ground of all ICs must be connected to V- and the power of all ICs to V+, right?

Comment: Right. And you have to be sure all ICs allow 10V between Vdd and Vss. Check Pin4 of IC6, it's wrongly connected to GND instead of V-.

Comment: I did everything, rechecked everything. Every connection is like that. The helicopter continues and as I increase the volume the helicopter pitch increases frequency. The only way to make the helicopter go, is to connect all jack's grounds to V-. Then it works fine. Pure sound, near zero noise, but the problem is that I cannot increase the volume up to a point. if I do, the sound sounds like it is being clipped. I have a power led connected between V- and V+ and as the sound is being "clipped" the led turns off momentarily. I have measured the voltage going down.... continues

Comment: (continued)... the external power adapter is 12V x 1A. Ah, another thing, as I increase the volume and the sound becomes to "clip" the 7810 starts to getting hot very fast. I know I am bothering you too much with this. I just felt that I needed to post this to tell the state of the thing right now. If you do not want to answer I understand and I would like to thank you for the previous help.

Comment: Ah, you are still with the 7810. That's the problem.

Comment: do you mean to use just the op amp? I am using the 7810 before the op amp.

Comment: The correct way to have a split power supply is connecting the GND split on the single-supply power, create a virtual GND at Vin/2, then use a positive regulator in the V+ (Vdd) line, and a negative regulator in the V- (Vss) line, both referring to that virtual GND.

Comment: ok, I see, thanks. If I understood correctly what you said, [this would be the new circuit](https://i.imgur.com/G6HkFyz.png)

Comment: Power to the LM358 has to go to the input + and -. What's the input voltage? For an 7806+7906, you need at least 18V.

Comment: I was using 12V but because I am redesigning it, I am now using 18V. I have finished it as you said and now I have 6V, 0 and -6V and the helicopter continues if the jacks' grounds are connected to the virtual ground. If I connect them to V- the helicopter is gone. I think this helicopter problem has to do with something incorrect on the TEA2025B. I am trying to understand this IC but the datasheet was designed by satan himself and the is no detailed explanation whatsoever about its pins. The explanation is superficial.

Comment: Ahhh, your outputs are driving speakers directly. Then, V- is correct. You could even connect one speaker to V-, one to V+, that would give you an even current draw on both voltage regulators. The reason is you use 470µF decoupling caps, which float the speaker potential. You could leave out those caps and tie the speakers to GND if your virtual GND had enough power to drive the speakers, too. What's better depends on whether you can live with the size and limited lifetime of big aluminium electrolytic caps. A pro of a strong strong ground vs. caps is also less speaker popping at turnon.

Comment: I did everything according to what you said. The helicopter problem vanished but there is a noise that is a kind of whistle/white noise that changes pitch and oscillates slightly as the volume is increased. The kind of noise changes as I change the power adapter. So, two things here: the amplifier is not working well (I would say it is oscillating) and noise from the power supply is reaching the amplifier and being amplified somehow.

Comment: As you have no oscilloscope, this is extra hard to debug. Try inserting mH size coils in the power supply lines (both Vin+ and Vin-) and see if the high-pitch noise is affected.